# Why is assigning a file pointer to a structure pointer member causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct CCSV {
    FILE *file;
} CCSV;

CCSV *csv_open(char *filename) {    
    CCSV *csv;

    csv->file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (csv->file == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return csv;
}

int main(void) {
    CCSV *csv = csv_open("cars.csv");

    if (csv == NULL) {
        puts("CSV File doesn't exist.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Specifically with the `csv_open` function, I am trying to assign `csv->file` with `fopen(filename, "r")`, but it's causing a segmentation fault. I've been searching online and trying to fix this, but nothing would work.

Why is assigning the file pointer to a structure pointer member causing a segmentation fault?

Comment: You're dereferencing a pointer to memory that is unallocated. Use `malloc`: `CCSV *csv = malloc(sizeof(*csv))`.

Comment: For some reason, when I return NULL (the `if (csv->file == NULL)`), it's also returning segmentation fault even with the dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: I don't see that a segfault would occur based on the code you've shown here as long as you call `malloc` as shown above or in tadman's answer. Is the code you're running exactly the same as this with that one change?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/39c7db161de690167760a4ac89ca7d79 I freed and closed the file, as I put `puts("CSV File doesn't exist.");`, segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: I closed the file first, then freed.

Comment: Please post the code as a new question or as a link. It's pointless for me to try to guess, but the code here with the `malloc` modification only won't segfault so I can't reproduce your new problem.

Comment: `fclose(csv->file)` is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: Well if the open failed, don't try to close a dead file. I recommend working on minimizing your code. If you check whether `csv->file` is null you can boil your problem down to `fclose(NULL)` which should give you a strong indication of what the issue is and how to fix it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even realize about dead files. That fixed the problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line creates a pointer, but this pointer is uninitialized and unallocated:

```
CCSV *csv;
```

You should be allocating:

```
CCSV *csv = malloc(sizeof(CCSV));
```

You should also `free()` this when you're done.

In C you need to be very careful to release any memory you've allocated. The way you've defined this function it leaks memory on errors. To fix that, reorganize it a bit:

```
CCSV *csv_open(char *filename) {    
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;

    CCSV *csv = malloc(sizeof(CCSV));

    csv->file = file;

    return csv;
}
```

This way if there's an error you won't get to the allocation stage, but if you do allocate you will return it.

Comment: Oh, could you give me a reason why I have to `malloc` that? Also, do you know why for some reason `if (file == NULL)` and the statements are causing segmentation fault even with malloc?

Comment: I'm not sure what CCSV is, many C libraries have things like `make_csv()` which allocates the structure for you, so you may want to double-check how you're supposed to allocate these. You *must* allocate if you're using a pointer, there is no alternative here, or you're just stomping over some random location in memory which will probably lead to an immediate crash (Segmentation Fault).

Comment: CCSV is a struct, it's in the code. https://gyazo.com/39c7db161de690167760a4ac89ca7d79 I freed and closed the file, as I put `puts("CSV File doesn't exist.");`, segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: If you're getting segmentation faults, next step is to run this in a debugger and find out why.

Comment: Ah, I see the definition now, it was hiding in plain sight.

Comment: `fclose(csv->file)` is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: That's not shown in your original code. Can you edit to include that?

Comment: It's worth noting that on failure you should **immediately exit `main()`**, like `return -1` to indicate error. Don't keep going.

Comment: ggorlen solved my problem, I was closing dead files, causing segmentation faults. But, thank you so much for the help!